# How to filter specific data from Axios response and use in additional calls

Tags: javascript, axios

[Could not get the code formatted "properly" to post the question unfortunately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9xL1.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

axios returns a promise object, so I don't think you can take the response data out from .then() like that.

here's how I would do it(May not be the best way, but it works)
Basically, make a promise to extract the data out(restructure the data from axios however you want first) and resolve the data outside.

```
const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
axios.get('whatever_url')
.then(response => {
const {shortdef, fl} = response.data.meta
resolve({shorted,fl})})
}
)
```

Note that you should probably add some logic to try and check for errors and implement a reject in your promise.